# Symbol is passed to 'raise'

Tags: ruby, exception

Code for context:

```
module Devise
  module Strategies
    class AuthxAuthenticatable < Authenticatable
      def valid?
        !params[scope].nil?
      end

      def authenticate!
        resource = mapping.to.authenticate_with_credentials(params[scope])
        return fail(:invalid) if resource.nil?
        success!(resource) if validate(resource)
      end
    end
  end
end

Warden::Strategies.add(:authx_authenticatable, Devise::Strategies::AuthxAuthenticatable)
```

Came across some code where a symbol is passed to `raise`:

```
raise(:invalid)
```

Doesn't look like there's any monkey patching of `raise` to handle symbol arguments. Seems like `fail` used to be used, and the code actually works if I use `fail`.

Isn't that just an alias for `raise`? Does this make sense in any context?

Comment: Yeah that should throw a `TypeError` with either `fail` or `raise`. Can you give more context? Any gems at play?

Comment: Thanks @hoffm. And yeah that's what I was thinking, posted some additional code above, essentially it's just a custom strategy for Devise

Comment: @hoffm looks like devise is using that syntax in some of its code as well

Comment: What version of Devise are you using? Looks like the latest doesn't do that https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/search?q=%22raise%22&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: @hoffm looks like it's mapped to the https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/config/locales/en.yml file

Comment: @hoffm sorry, looks like they're using it with the fail method https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/88724e10adaf9ffd1d8dbfbaadda2b9d40de756a/lib/devise/strategies/database_authenticatable.rb#L18

Comment: Ah, so it's just an implicit localization of a string then?

Comment: Must be something to that effect, but wouldn't the fail method have to be redefined somewhere to use a mapping scheme? Maybe they have their own gem at play...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157016/discussion-between-drew-and-hoffm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `fail` method being used was the warden method:

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/hassox/warden/Warden%2FStrategies%2FBase:fail